# Dynamically-populated fields in Gravity Forms for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to include Gravity Forms on my wordpress website. I wanted to use dynamically populated fields and looked up the docs that say:

> You can populate a field via the query string by appending the dynamic
>   population parameter you specified for the field to the end of your
>   form URL along with your custom value.
>
> http://siteurl.com/form-url/?your_parameter=value

I have made my first field dynamically populated and named the parameter "name".

Unfortunately when I type:

You can populate a field via the query string by appending the dynamic population parameter you specified for the field to the end of your form URL along with your custom value.

http://siteurl.com/form-url/?name=test

I'm getting an error `Error, Page not found`. Do I need to change something in my permalink section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable "All field to be populated dynamically" option for the field that you want to be populated by url parameter. Try using anything other than "name" for example "your_name" or "full_name". It will work properly.

[image]

Comment: Yes that is all done, I clicked that checkbox and put name of the parameter as "name", and then used it in URL as ?name=test  but when I do that I can't even access the form page

Comment: It seems "name" won't work as parameter.  Change it to  "full_name" in form field settings and then try  http://siteurl.com/form-url/?full_name=test
It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, I would never have guessed that "name" can't be the name of the parameter

Comment: I am trying to figure out why "name" can not be the parameter. If I can do that, i will let you know.

Comment: If anyone ever wonders; it's not possible because `name` is a [reserved term in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms).